# User credentials are not getting stored in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase

While registering for user, it is getting failed and gives exception in logcat as 
" I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@1a8a2b0 "

All the correct and updated dependencies are implemented.....

While clicking on signup button on android studio it is getting failed and gives the message as "Failed while registering, An internal error has occurred [7 :]"

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private TextView signIn;
    private Button registerBtn;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        email = findViewById(R.id.email_register);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password_register);
        registerBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        signIn = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_txt);

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                String myEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String myPass = password.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(myEmail))
                {
                    email.setError("This field is required.");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(myPass))
                {
                    password.setError("This field is required.");
                    return;
                }

                progressDialog.setMessage("Registering please wait...");
                progressDialog.show();

                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(myEmail, myPass).addOnCompleteListener(RegistrationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Registered...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed while registering..." + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Check that your Firebase dependencies are all up to date as shown in the release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Yeah, they are all up-to-date.